# HP 1515 deskjet blank pages

Tags: printing, hp, pdf

My printer's black cartridge has been changed. Now Images print but not .pdf files received by email. I installed `hplip 3.14.3` and checked that my model is supported in Ubuntu 14.04. Removed and reconnected the printer; no change. I got a CUPS server error"Broken pipe" with very long text file ending with:

```
Page 9 (Error log fetch):
{'error_log': ['D [18/Jun/2015:15:32:21 +0200] [Client 27] Sending file.',
               'D [18/Jun/2015:15:32:21 +0200] cupsd is not idle any more, canceling shutdown.',
               'D [18/Jun/2015:15:32:21 +0200] [Client 27] cupsdWriteClient error=0, used=0, state=HTTP_STATE_GET_SEND, data_encoding=HTTP_ENCODING_LENGTH, data_remaining=18563474, response=(nil)(), pipe_pid=0, file=29',
```